# Create a text box with an auto-expanding width?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, expand

How would I go about creating a textbox with an auto-expanding width to fit it's content?

I keep finding plenty of info on height based expansions but not much on width.

I'd also like it to apply to every textbox on the page and not just specific ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you had in mind, but shouldn't this work?

```
<script language="javascript">
function expand(f)
{
    f.size = f.size + 1;
}
</script>

<input type="text" size="20" onkeyup="expand(this)" />
```

Comment: cool. nice solution. but what happens if the user pushes backspace ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want backspace key handling use this:

```
<input type="text" value="Sample text" onkeyup="(event.keyCode!==8)?this.size++:this.size--;" size="20">
```

If you want backspace key handling and to ignore arrow keys use this one:

```
<input type="text" value="Sample text" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode==8){this.size--;}else if(event.keyCode!==37&&event.keyCode!==38&&event.keyCode!==39&&event.keyCode!==4‌​0){this.size++;}" size="6">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to check the length of the text and modify the textbox if the text was too long rather than checking for every type of key event that shouldn't trigger an expansion. An example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function expand(textbox){
    var minSize = 20;
    var contentSize = textbox.value.length;
    if(contentSize > minSize)
    {
        textboxSize = contentSize;
    }
    else
    {
        textboxSize = minSize;
    }
}
</script>
<input type="text" size="20" onkeyup="expand(this)" />
```