# How to make a div fill remaining space, and go to next line when necessary?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's an example of what I have so far as a demo:

[link to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AFcsM/)

And here's the CSS that I'm using right now:

```
body {
    background-color: darkgrey;    
}

.container {
    background: #ccc;
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.label {
    float: left;
}
.filler {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
.filler input {
    min-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a responsive way to add tags (almost exactly like the tag system on stackoverflow), to a div, whilst having the input always sit after the last entered tag div. So far I've accomplished this, except for when the last tag is pushed to the next line.

I'd really like a non-javascript solution, but if anyone has an elegant javascript solution I'm willing to take it!

Comment: I've decided to just have an input with a fixed width, and floated left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be of any use? I'm no pro with javascript and I haven't tested it, but it looks simple. Sounds like all you need is a way to get backspace to subtract width.

[Create a text box with an auto-expanding width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085819/create-a-text-box-with-an-auto-expanding-width)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vGWCR/

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem of not filling the remaining space on the line. As well as forcing an extra line when not  necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`:

**CSS**

```css
.label {
    display: inline-block;
}
.filler {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AFcsM/1/)**

Comment: Though this does solve the issue of not continuing to the next line, it does not fill the remaining horizontal-space. I'm thinking I may need to include a trace of javascript right now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a code solution, but maybe an existing plugin can help.  For example: [jQuery Tags Input Plugin](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) ?   I am sure there are others, but maybe reuse, unless your use case is significantly different?

(I would have just added a comment, but my rep ins't high enough yet :) )

Comment: My use case isn't significantly different, but there's some specific functionality that I need that I feel many plugins won't offer. Though I may do some research into a few and see if there's one that is expandable, or will offer me exactly what I need in some form. :)